# Migrating Server - Craft isn't installed yet

Tags: database, error-message, server, services

I've set up a new Forge server and connected the repo to my site. I've also uploaded the database and copied over the db credentials to the dotenv file. However when I visit the site control panel continue to see this

[image]

Have created new db, imported and changed credentials. Still same
Have ftp'd into the server and can confirm all files are there

Is there something else I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried running ./craft setup to double check if your setup is correct?

If ./craft setup completes successfully ./craft should find the existing installation and complete any required setup.

In my experience, this is usually related to a non-default /config/db.php or problematic .env file.

Note: Always do a backup before trying anything related to setup just to be on the safe side.